# How to restore wlan profile from Microsoft saved settings?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, backup

I'm using Windows 10. When I'm using my previous notebook, I logged in using Microsoft account, and connected to many different wireless networks - only few of them I use regularly, but importantly, many of them are free and I might come back and need to use them - cafe or restaurant.

Now I'm using a different notebook with Windows 10, and since I logged in using the same Microsoft account, the wlan profile is synced.

Unfortunately, today's my wifi is acting up, and I tried a Network Reset, which proved unsuccessful. I managed to fix it after setting up WLAN Autoconfig Service to Auto, instead of Manual.

Now I just realized that all of my saved wifi passwords are gone.

Since Microsoft saved the wireless profile (in their cloud), **is there any hope to restore those passwords?** (before they got overwritten by my current empty profile)

Note: It doesn't have to be from Microsoft cloud. For example, if there is a backup file hidden somewhere. I haven't backup the profiles before.

Comment: If you have logged out of the profile after you wiped the passwords, the cloud copy is gone, but if you disable syncing on the both devices and the one with passwords already stored then you can resync the passwords in theory (musical chairs)

Comment: The current notebook replaced the old one, so I don't have access to the notebook anymore. And the old one of course has already been logged out, if that matters.

Comment: Then the profiles cannot be restored

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do a System Restore just before the problem.

Just go to the Control Panel > Recovery > Open System Restore
Select the most recent restore point, and proceed with the system restore.